# How do I use collection for-loops in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add widgets in a `SliverList` using a `for`-loop.
But I get the following error:

> error: The element type 'Set' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

The problem arises here:

```dart
slivers: [
  for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    EachBusInfoBodyWidget(Colors.green)
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the [collection for operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators) does not take curly braces (`{}`). i.e. they do not work with them as you can tell.
Curly braces are used for `Set` and `Map` literals. If you add a colon behind an entry, it becomes a `Map` literal, e.g. `{ 'flavor': 'sweet' }`. However, if you just use curly braces, it creates a `Set`. Usually this does not affect for-loops because curly braces are used as regular flow control.

Anyways, to fix the issue you simply need to remove your curly braces:

```dart
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) EachBusInfoBodyWidget(Colors.green)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `build` method as follows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//insert
List<Widget> widgets = List<Widget>();          

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  widgets.add(EachBusInfoBodyWidget(Colors.green));                  
}
//end insert
return Scaffold(
```

And also change your `CustomScrollView`:

```
     child: CustomScrollView(
      slivers:
      <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
           //insert
            widgets
           //end insert
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Comment: The author specifically wanted to use the collection for feature.

Comment: question was edited. delete the answer if incorrect.